# Detecting eye contact in image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I am hoping to develop a way to try to detect if a person is actually looking at the camera in an image (or via a webcam), I realize that any implementation would have low accuracy, but any accuracy at all would be significant. I have found a lot of good examples using the webcam and HTML5.

http://techslides.com/object-detection-with-html5-getusermedia/

I've also found some really useful code in this project:

https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/

And in this one:

http://trackingjs.com/

But all of these focus on head movement, and facial recognition. Is there any implementation in any language that has any success in this? Or is it basically impossible right now? If it exists in a different language other than javascript, thats ok, as long as its open source I could see how they have developed an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We once created a game which tracks your eyes, [here's an working example](http://ghost.kreativrudel.de/). The eye tracking is not 100% accurate since it was an 24 hours hackathon project :) and it heavily depends on the environment and the person (in dark environments and people wearing glasses or even with asian people the detection doesn't work properly). I think with some tweaks you could achieve great results with it.

We used [jsfeat](https://github.com/inspirit/jsfeat) for the eyetracking since it is more performant than trackingjs.

[Here is our project on github if you're interested.](https://github.com/micron/staring-contest)